# AOSP : How to add service in service manager after removal of android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" from manifest

Tags: android-source, servicemanager

Unable to start service . Line is added in onCreate of service.

```
<pre>ServiceManager.addService(ACTION_REMOTE_SERVICE, (IBinder) new xxxRemoteservice(this));</pre>
```

Changes we removed android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" from manifest . But the application is signed with platform certificate And LOCAL_VENDOR_MODULE := true

```
Getting error below

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:764)
    at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:150)
    at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:88)
```